# In regex, if any character exists after "a" or "b", it must be a forward slash ( / ) character. how can i reach that?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want it matches any sting like `a/` or `a` or `a/word` but not `ac/` or `ac` or ...

Comment: Give some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `a` and `b` in a character class and look for a slash `/` or end of input string immediately afterwards:

```
/[ab](?:\/|$)/
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbKI0B/1)